# MySQL Select parent row from a many to many relation pivot

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `products`, `ingredients` and `ingredient_product`.

I need to find all `products`, where the product has the related ingredients.
It also needs to have a matching value on the `percentage` column.

A product exists with two ingredients related.

```
+-----+------------+---------------+------------+
| id  | product_id | ingredient_id | percentage |
+-----+------------+---------------+------------+
|   1 |          1 |            1 |         50  |
|   2 |          1 |            2 |         50  |
+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

SQL to retrieve:

```
SELECT
      products.id
    FROM
      products,
      ingredient_product
    WHERE
        ingredient_product.product_id = products.id
    AND
        (ingredient_product.ingredient_id = 1 AND ingredient_product.percentage = 50)
    AND
        (ingredient_product.ingredient_id = 2 AND ingredient_product.percentage = 50)
```

But this returns an empty result. `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Products:

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| short_description | text                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| long_description  | text                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Ingredients:

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| short_name        | varchar(50)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail         | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ingredient_product

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ingredient_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| percentage    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Both AND clauses cannot be true at same time, use ingredient_product.ingredient_id IN (1,2)

Comment: @mitkosoft If you have the SQL to solve the question, please put it as a reply. That way I can accept.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Strawberries answer:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM ingredient_product 
WHERE ingredient_id IN (1,2) AND percentage = 50
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

However this doesn't work if you need separate percentages, but you can do this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM
    (SELECT product_id 
    FROM ingredient_product 
    WHERE ingredient_id = 1 AND percentage = 50
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM ingredient_product 
    WHERE ingredient_id = 2 AND percentage = 50) AS tmp
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Essentially you add a `UNION` for each requirement (consisting of an id and percentage combo) and then increase the `HAVING` condition to the number of requirements.

Notes: Since the requirements are mutually exclusive in this case, `UNION ALL` is quicker than `UNION` and will give you the same result.

Instead of an `UNION` in a subquery you could use `OR` but we found that MySQL seems to like this format better. That however might change from version to version. For completeness sake here that solution as well:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM ingredient_product 
WHERE (ingredient_id = 1 AND percentage = 50) OR (ingredient_id = 2 AND percentage = 50)
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that id is redundant, and that you have a perfectly serviceable natural key on (product_id,ingredient_id)...

```
SELECT product_id 
  FROM ingredient_product 
 WHERE ingredient_id IN (1,2) 
 GROUP 
    BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: That doesn't match the percentage column on the pivot table.

Comment: If my question is unclear, let me know which bit and I will try and clarify.

Comment: @CharliePrynn I know. See if you can figure that bit out.

Comment: @Stawberry I'm not sure thats the best idea as if someone else has the same question and reviews this question, only part of the answer is here.